# how to send data to firebase database in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send data to firebase. The data is saved to the database after the function is performed, how can I overwrite it during the function execution?

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

var db = firebase.database();
var sleep = require('sleep');
function run(TIME) {
  db.ref('/test/').child('status').set('1');
  sleep.sleep(TIME);
  db.ref('/test/').child('status').set('2');
  sleep.sleep(TIME);
  db.ref('/test/').child('status').set('3');
  sleep.sleep(TIME);
  db.ref('/test/').child('status').set('4');

};
//========================================<<<< Now I see status in Firebase
run(5);
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what you try to achieve? Thx

Comment: I want to have status in firebase. WORKING - before starting function and DONE after.

Answer (score 1):

The `set()` method is asynchronous and returns a promise that resolves when write to server is complete, as explained in the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set).

From you comment above I understand you want to have a status "WORKING - before starting function and DONE after".

So you should do something along the following lines:

```
var status = '';
var adaNameRef = firebase.database().ref('users/ada/name');
status = 'WORKING';
adaNameRef.set({ first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace' })
  .then(function() {
    status = 'DONE'; 
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Synchronization failed');
  });
```

If you want to "write multiple values to the Database at once", you should use the `update()` method. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Similarly to the `set()` method, the `update()` method is asynchronous and returns a promise that resolves when write to server is complete, so you would use the same logic to update the value of status

---

UPDATE following your comment

*1. Send status 'WORKING' to FB 2. Set Relay to ON 3. Wait x seconds 4. Send status 'DONE' to FB 5. Set Relay to OFF*

If I understood correctly, this should work (not tested however):

```
var adaNameRef = firebase.database().ref('users/ada/name');
adaNameRef.set({ status: 'WORKING'})
  .then(function() {
    // Set Relay to ON  ... don't know exactly how you "set the relay"
    sleep.sleep(x);
    return adaNameRef.set({ status: 'DONE'})
  })
  .then(function() {
    // Set Relay to OFF 
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Renaud, 
thank you for help, I want send status to firebase.

Comment: @Tom Not 100% sure what you want to do but by mixing sleep and asynchronous methods triggered in // you will probably get strange results. If you explain really in detail what you want to do we may help further.

Comment: I want:
1. Send status 'WORKING' to FB
2. Set Relay to ON
3. Wait x seconds
4. Send status 'DONE' to FB
5. Set Relay to OFF

Thank you @Renaud